# Pathifier bioconductor package recommends to use technical noise for an argument. How to determine it?

Tags: statistics, microarray, pathway

I'm running the [pathifier](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/pathifier.html) approach against C2 pathway curated
database for a specific microarray dataset.

As I was reading the documentation of the pathifier, in order to configure it properly for my dataset, I saw that for the `min_std` argument they suggest to use the technical noise.

> min_std:   The minimal allowed standard deviation of each gene. Genes
> with lower standard deviation are divided by min_std instead of their
> actual standard deviation. (Recommended: set min_std to be the
> technical noise).

But how am I going to calculate it ? At first run I just used the value `0.2254005` from the example they provide with that package, but this might not be the right for my dataset.

Update:

So from [here](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/complex/compphys/software/yotam/pathifier/help.htm) it says: `The minimal standard error (min_std) was set as the first quartile of the standard deviation in the data`. How am I supposed to calculate this first quartile of the std? Any idea? Should I calculate the sd() for each gene and then find the first quartile?

What do you think about this [function](https://pastebin.com/ni5uKhpX)?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @llrs, converted from comment:*

Probably is a question for the maintainer but I would *guess* that is a variance of the gene in the control dataset. So, if in normal samples the gene has a standard deviation of 0.5 this is the expected too in the tumoral cells. calculate the sd only on the control samples. So if the healthy/control samples have such variation the altered ones should have these or more according to the article (if I understand it correctly).

`std <- apply(data[, controls], 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE); quantile(std, 0.25)` should be much faster and efficient

But  I would check it in [support.bioconductor](https://support.bioconductor.org) with the authors/maintainers.